# Adding styling on an anchor tag inside list item tag

Tags: html, css

I am adding styling on an anchor tag which is inside li tag.
But Styling is not Applying to It.

This is HTML CODE

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" id="Shop_Active" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="Store1.php">Store 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Store2.php">Store 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is CSS CODE :

```
<style>
li a #Shop_Active   /* For Inserting an underline On Shop Button */
{
    style=border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #3399FF;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You’ve got invalid CSS like `style=`; and `a #Shop_Active` doesn’t mean “the `<a>` element with the ID `Shop_Active`”, it means “the element with the ID `Shop_Active` _inside_ an `<a>` element”. Why don’t you just use `#Shop_Active`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: is with your selector `li a #Shop_Active` .. The meaning of this is .. find a element which has a id `Shop_Active` which is a child of `a` which inturn is child of `li`

But what you want is to find a `a` tag with that given Id. Not a child element in it.

**Solution**: Remove the space after your `a`

`li a #Shop_Active`  this should be

`li a#Shop_Active`

Or simply

`#Shop_Active {
 /* Your rules*/ 
}`

since ID's are meant to be unique